# Cross-Version Conflicts with Spark and Azure-Cosmosdb

Tags: scala, azure, apache-spark, sbt, azure-cosmosdb

I've been banging my head on this one for a while now and I'm officially stuck. I'm trying to compile a jar containing a simple scala/spark job that runs on Azure Databricks, including a dependency on CosmosDB. Importing the `azure-cosmosdb-spark` introduces conflicting cross version errors during compilation, which I assume is a result of some transitive dependancy. I've tried a number of different spark and scala versions, but no help, and the error messages dont tell much.

My minimal example to reproduce the error is simply a `build.sbt`, no scala classes are being compiled at the moment. An example of my `build.sbt` is below:

```
name := "ranchero"

version := "0.0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
val sparkVersion = "2.2.0"

// additional libraries
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" %  sparkVersion % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % sparkVersion % "provided",
  "joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.9.9",
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.0" % "test",
  "com.microsoft.azure" % "azure-cosmosdb-spark_2.2.0_2.11" % "1.1.0"
)


resolvers ++= Seq(
  "apache-snapshots" at "http://repository.apache.org/snapshots/",
  "Maven central" at "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/",
 )
```

if I comment out the cosmosdb dependency, things compile just fine. With that dep added, I get errors of the flavor:

```
[error] Modules were resolved with conflicting cross-version suffixes in {file:/home/*******/development/ranchero/}ranchero:
[error]    org.apache.spark:spark-launcher _2.10, _2.11
[error]    org.json4s:json4s-ast _2.10, _2.11
[error]    org.apache.spark:spark-network-shuffle _2.10, _2.11
[error]    com.twitter:chill _2.10, _2.11
[error]    org.json4s:json4s-jackson _2.10, _2.11
[error]    com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala _2.10, _2.11
[error]    org.json4s:json4s-core _2.10, _2.11
[error]    org.apache.spark:spark-unsafe _2.10, _2.11
[error]    org.apache.spark:spark-core _2.10, _2.11
[error]    org.apache.spark:spark-network-common _2.10, _2.11
[error] java.lang.RuntimeException: Conflicting cross-version suffixes in: org.apache.spark:spark-launcher, org.json4s:json4s-ast, org.apache.spark:spark-network-shuffle, com.twitter:chill, org.json4s:json4s-jackson, com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala, org.json4s:json4s-core, org.apache.spark:spark-unsafe, org.apache.spark:spark-core, org.apache.spark:spark-network-common
```

which, unfortunately doesn't offer much help. Any suggestions for how to to rectify this?

Answer (score 1):

Let sbt handle the scala version for all the dependencies. Try to replace the azure-cosmosdb dependency with this:

```
"com.microsoft.azure" %% "azure-cosmosdb-spark_2.2.0" % "1.1.0"
```

The double percent will tell sbt to handle the scala version tag for dependencies. At least sbt shell starts with corrected build.sbt.

Answer (score 1):

While I agree on the handling of the Scala version via `%%`, this did not suffice in my case. I finally managed, to get it to work by manually excluding the offending dependencies from the CosmosDB library

```
"com.microsoft.azure" %% "azure-cosmosdb-spark_2.2.0" % "1.1.1"
   exclude ("org.apache.spark", "spark-launcher_2.10")
   exclude ("org.json4s", "json4s-ast_2.10")
   exclude ("org.apache.spark", "spark-network-shuffle_2.10")
   exclude ("com.twitter", "chill_2.10")
   exclude ("org.json4s", "json4s-jackson_2.10")
   exclude ("com.fasterxml.jackson.module", "jackson-module-scala_2.10")
   exclude ("org.json4s", "json4s-core_2.10")
   exclude ("org.apache.spark", "spark-unsafe_2.10")
   exclude ("org.apache.spark", "spark-core_2.10")
   exclude ("org.apache.spark", "spark-network-common_2.10")
```

This assumes you are using Scala 2.11 in your project. I don't have an explanation for why this is necessary though. Maybe the 2.11 CosmosDB library on Maven for some reason is linked to 2.10 dependencies...